# Forcing cached image reload

Tags: javascript, angularjs, node.js

So I'm trying to make a user profile picture directive that accepts a userid as a parameter and displays the image inline. I'm using NodeJS/Express 4.x on the server end and Angular 1.2.25 for frontend. The only reason I've decided on using a directive at all is because if I attempt to use `<img ng-src="/someurl">`, I get a 403 server response because the image request was not sent through the http interceptor. The directive and controller are given below:

```
.directive('profileImg', ['AuthToken', function (AuthToken) {
  return {
  restrict: 'E',
  controller: AuthWrapperProfile,
  scope: {
    userid: '@',
    css: '@',
    style: '@'
  },
  template: '<img ng-src="{{url}}" style="{{style}}" class="{{css}}"></img>'
 }
}]);

AuthWrapperProfile.$inject = ['AuthToken', '$scope'];
function AuthWrapperProfile(AuthToken, $scope) {
  $scope.token = AuthToken.getToken();

  // initial image url once userid is loaded
  $scope.$watch('userid', function () {
  $scope.url = '/api/avatar/' + $scope.userid + '?token=' + $scope.token 
      + '&cb=' + Date.now(); // Added to URL to force reload

  });

  // update picture based on update event being fired
  var listener = $scope.$on('avatar:update', function (event, data) {
    $scope.url = '/api/avatar/' + $scope.userid + '?token=' + $scope.token 
         + '&cb=' + Date.now(); // Added to URL to force reload
  });

  // clean up listener
  $scope.$on('$destroy', listener);
};
```

Problem:
Whenever a user profile is updated to reflect a different profile picture, the only way I have been able to fiuund out how to force angular/browser to reload the picture is by appending a URL parameter of Date.now which causes it to reload on every single call to get the image.

Is there a way to somehow flag the URL as changed once so that the proper image can be reloaded and cached? Or is there a better way of doing this?

Comment: Appending `Date.now` is a valid approach, but the best way would be to set the proper `Cache-Control` headers on the image itself so that it isn't cached for too long by the browser. This, of course, needs to be done server-side.

Comment: Thanks for the response. For the time being, I was able to get around the issue by using `window.location.reload()`, forcing the browser to reload the entire page. I will have to look into Node cache control for a more elegant solution later

Comment: page reload doesn't prevent browser caching. Sounds like you had other problems